# Why is remix telling me "expected primary expression" where I declared my modifier?

Tags: solidity, remix

Why is remix telling me "expected primary expression" when I declare my modifier?

```
contract Autos {

// <-------- EXTENDED CONSTRUCTOR FOR TEST PURPOSES ----------->

constructor() public {

address owner;
owner = msg.sender;


bool ifmember;
mapping(address => bool) members;

modifier onlyMember {
    require(msg.sender == owner || members[msg.sender] == true);
    _;
    }


function addMember(address _address) public onlyMember {
    ifmember = members[_address];
    }



}

// <--------------------- END CONSTRUCTOR --------------------->
```

When I create a new SOL with just the following, I get no error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Autos {

address public owner;
mapping(address => bool) members;


modifier onlyMember {
    require(msg.sender == owner || members[msg.sender] == true);
    _;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't declare functions or modifiers within the constructor. It should be something like this:

```
contract Autos {
    address owner; 

    bool ifmember;
    mapping(address => bool) members;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyMember {
        require(msg.sender == owner || members[msg.sender] == true);
        _;
    }
    function addMember(address _address) public onlyMember {
        ifmember = members[_address];
    }
}
```